# Is there any way to have a Unity TextMeshPro dropdown option with a different font than the others in the list?

Tags: unity-game-engine, menu, dropdown

I am using TextMeshPro Dropdowns in Unity as the basis for my menu system. The problem is Unity TMP Dropdowns require one option to be selected at all times, and clicking the already selected option won't trigger the "On Value Changed" function for processing the option.

Thus the only solution I am aware of is to have the first option be a dummy option like "CHOOSE:" or "SELECT ONE:" which is then the initially selected option. This is not too bad but it would be better if it was possible to at least make it a different font (for example, bold) so it looks intentional.

From what I can see however, there is no way to script or code anything to change the font size/color/face of only one option in a dropdown.

Is this possible or would there be another suggested solution to the problem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [RichText](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.ugui@1.0/manual/StyledText.html) tags for setting string literals, something like

```
List < string > m_DropOptions = new List < string > { "<size=19><i>Select something</i></size>", "Option 1", "Option 2" };
```

Now **Select something** will be italic and with a different font size. You can always explore RichText link to find information that suite the needs of the application.

Output:

[image]

Comment: Wow that is absolutely fantastic and incredibly helpful. I didn't know you could do that. I now have color, size, bold, italics, and underline all at my disposal. That alone is great. But I also see on the RichText page a `material` option. Would this allow me to change the font? If so where would I add and identify the different material for the TMP Dropdown items? Or if not no worries. I'd appreciate you letting me know either way if it is possible so I know the limitations. This was already super helpful. Thank you very much.

Comment: I am really sorry but I hadn't used the whole APIs myself. I just knew that Unity does support some HTML like tags. Hadn't played much with TextMeshPro yet. Glad the link did helped you in some way. For the rest YOU'RE MOST WELCOME and KEEP SMILING :-)

Comment: No worries. Thanks again.

Comment: TextMesh Pro adds substantial amount of new rich text tags, one of which lets you change the font: http://digitalnativestudios.com/textmeshpro/docs/rich-text/#font